# Left-join foreach loop over array with nested array

Tags: php, foreach, left-join

I have two tables one for users and one for their reviews. On one page I need to show thumbnails of each user and the reviews that match that user. The problem is the LEFT JOIN creates a row for every time there is a review. So if a user has two reviews they are showing up twice in the list of thumbnails. Do I need a loop inside the loop? Everything I can think of seems really clunky. Thanks.

```
    // Get Data
$qry  = "SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `reviews` ON users.userId = reviews.user_id WHERE installation_id = $installation_id";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error($mysqli));

//$uqry = "SELECT membership FROM users WHERE userId = $uid";
//$current_user = mysqli_query($mysqli, $uqry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error($mysqli));

$getUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT membership FROM users WHERE userId = $uid"));
$currentUserLevel = $getUser['membership'];



?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <?php if ($msgBox) { echo $msgBox; } ?>
        <div class="row">       

        <?php $lists = array(); 
            while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                  $lists[] = $list;
                }

                foreach($lists as $list) { 
                        $name = stripslashes($list['usersName']); 
                        $bio  = stripslashes($list['usersBio']); 
                        $review  = stripslashes($list['comments']);
                        $stars  = stripslashes($list['stars']); ?>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id = "user-square">  
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $avatarDir.$list['usersAvatar']; ?>" class="publicAvatar" />
                                </div>
                                Name:<?php echo $name; ?> <br /> 
                                Bio:<?php echo $bio;  ?> <br />     
                                Review:<?php echo $review;  ?> <br />   
                                Stars: <?php echo $stars;  ?> <br />                    

                                <?php 
                                    if ($currentUserLevel == 'pro') {
                                    echo 'CONTACT SCOUT';
                                }
                                    else {
                                    echo 'Sorry you must upgrade to a Pro membership to contact this Scout';    
                                }   
                                ?>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
            <?php   }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guess it depends how you want the reviews to be displayed. If the user has more than one review, do you want to show all the reviews, or just the first one? How will that look on the page? Going by your HTML above, you seem to only want to show one review per user.

Comment: I see that could be misleading. I would like to show each review. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to navigate the result printing out a new row for every review and giving me multiple results of the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `while` loop to the following:

```
while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      $lists[$list['usersName']][$list['usersBio']][$list['stars']][] = $list['comments'];
}
```

That will give you a nice multidimensional array with the user name as the first key, and all that users reviews ordered by star rating. You should probably use a unique key rather than the users name as there could be duplicates, so either the email or unique row ID would be better.

You can then (VERY basic example):

```
$reviews = "";
foreach($lists as $username => $array) {
    foreach($array as $bio => $array2) {

        $name = stripslashes($username); 
        $bio  = stripslashes($bio); 

        foreach($array2 as $stars => $comments_array) {

            $stars  = stripslashes($stars);

            foreach($comments_array as $comments) {

                $reviews .= $stars . " - " . stripslashes($comments) . "<br />";

            }

        }

        // Your HTML here using $name, $bio, and $reviews(which will be star rating followed review for that user each on a new line)
        echo '
            <table width="400">
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $name . '</td><td>' . $bio . '</td><td>' . $reviews . '</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ';


    }

    $reviews = "";

}
```

Comment: This is def a help, but still hasn't offered the complete solution. Maybe I am not understanding what should go in the HTML area, but each person either shows the same review for everyone or only shows one reviews. Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry there were a couple of typos, I have edited the solution. I have added an example of the HTML output using a table, and also reset the `$reviews` variable to empty at the end of the first `foreach`, otherwise like you say it just keeps appending all the reviews with each loop. I have tested the above and it now works as it should.

Comment: Hi I have just one last question for you since I can't seem to figure this out on my own. How would I should just the average stars for the person. I have tried to work with that stars variable but I just get 1 every time which I guess is the string length.

Comment: I don't know what the content of your `$stars` variable looks like.